# Discord.JS strange issue when attempting to update VoiceChannel

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, bots

So I'm getting the error 'Type: value "voice" is not int.' when attempting to update a voice channel name but only on Ubuntu.
`message.guild.channels.cache.get('863162796262031410').setName('testing')`

*Please note, this is happening on Ubuntu but works fine on windows*

If anyone can provide some insight it would be greatly appreciated.

```
Uncaught Promise Error:  DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body
 type: Value "voice" is not int.
     at RequestHandler.execute (/home/NodeJS/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:152:13)
     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:93:5)
     at async RequestHandler.push (/home/NodeJS/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:37:14)
     at async VoiceChannel.edit (/home/NodeJS/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/GuildChannel.js:357:21) {
   method: 'patch',
   path: '/channels/863162796262031410',
   code: 50035,
   httpStatus: 400
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

A way you can do this and it will work is:

## Option One

```js
const voiceChannel = message.guild.channels.resolve('channel_id')
voiceChannel.setName('new_channel_name');
```

## Option 2

```js
const voiceChannel = message.guild.channels.resolve('channel_id');
voiceChannel.edit({
    name: 'testing',
})
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I have tried that before and again just now but it still fails in the linux environment for some reason with the same error.

Comment: What discord version are you on? @No1'sPerfect

Comment: Also, added a different answer that might help

Comment: discord.js@12.5.3

Comment: still seems to be returning the same issue with the second option sadly.